# Problem with subspace projections

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I have been looking at some exercises about vector x being projected onto subspaces but I have a question. 
In the exercises I solved, the subspace onto which the vector x is projected happens to be horizontal. 
I understand that the basic procedure is to decompose x in a vertical and horizontal component.
In the exercise forementioned they logically claim the horizontal component coincides with the projection of a x onto the subspace because our subspace is horizontal.
However, what happens if the subspace formed by the vectors is not horizontal?

Comment: It is not clear what is meant by horizontal

Comment: What does ‘horizontal’ mean, mathematically?

Comment: By horizontal I mean parallel to the xy plane

Comment: That happened because the third components of the spanning vectors of the subspace happened to be the same.

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer?

Comment: In my exercise, the basis is indeed orthonormal, but still, does the claim that the projection of a vector x  onto the subspace equals the parallel component of the vector x always hold?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the parallel component". Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment meant for me, you have to put @Gerry into it.

Comment: Are you still here, Time?

Comment: @Gerry. Yes, but I already solved it. It turned out that the idea of the exercise was that any vector can be expressed as a sum of an element of a subspace S and another element from the orthogonal of S.

Comment: Good. Why not write up what you now know, and post it as an answer?

Comment: Why not today??

Comment: I will write it as soon as I can

Comment: Two months later, still waiting for your answer, Time traveler.

Answer (score 0):

If the subspace in question has an orthonormal basis $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ then the projection of $v$ onto that subspace is $(v\cdot v_1)v_1+(v\cdot v_2)v_2+\cdots+(v\cdot v_n)v_n$.

If you don't have an orthonormal basis for the subspace, life is more complicated.